# Is there a way to create a hidden form field that is automatically filled with the name of a product?

Tags: javascript, forms, email

I'm new to all the dynamic stuff that can be done in web programming. I am building an eBay store and I have a contact form created already. However, I would really like to have a hidden field that tells me the product name that someone is asking about. Is there a way to get the product name when the form generates?

Sorry this may seem really vague or generic. I'll post code if needed. Not sure what code I would need to post. <-- newb :)

Thanks

Comment: This would usually be done server-side (if I'm understanding you correctly). The app would put the value in your field prior to sending the page to the browser. If that's not what you're after you'll need to explain where JavaScript would get the product name.

Comment: You can do it during form generation.Create an input field with type hidden and pass the value. What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that loads for example on page load.

```
window.load = preloadInputs;

function preloadInputs(){
  var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('id_of_your_hidden_input');

  hiddenInput.value = "foo"; // if you need help with this part ask
}
```

I assume you know where you can get the values.

Comment: I think I understand this. The name of the product is currently just text in my "Description" section of the page. Would I need to create a value somewhere that has the name so this code can grab it?

Comment: That's a thing of what architectures you use. If you use something that is generating the html (php,java,etc) on the serverside, you can actually create that input `type="hidden"` on  the serverside. If the content is generated via ajax or e.g. you would have to create the value as you said.

Comment: Ok sorry still new to all this, so stupid question; how would I find out how my content is being created? All I know is I upload the files thru FTP and it shows up where I want it. I have a PHP script for running the mail FORM but that is all.

Comment: Do you have a link, where I could have a look on that?

Comment: www.esellersnwa.com/pending/index.html